# How to detect and remove trailing backslash from end of string?

Tags: python, string

An entry of any file has a trailing backslash

```
cache[path] = file.read()
for file_name, multi_line_content in cache.items():
   for line in multi_line_content.splitlines():
      // this line may or maynot have trailing backslash
```

Ex:

`dsf  dff  dfdf \`

`cvcs dsd sdds\`

---

How to process this line, detect trailing backslash and remove it, before the copying the complete line as string?

Comment: Is this a text file you are reading from a python program, or a line in the python?

Comment: @MartinBonner  This is a multiline string `cache[path] = file.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) is just what you need:

```
s = s.rstrip('\\')
```

Comment: That will remove *all* trailing backslashes (which may or may not be what the OP wants).

Comment: Removing looks obvious.. detecting is the problem

Comment: @overexchange they aren't separate problems. `rstrip` will remove trailing backslahes if they exist. If they don't, the string will be returned unchanged.

Comment: Are you saying that `for line in multi_line_content.splitlines():` is safe?

Comment: @overexchange should be, yes.

Comment: Can I rstrip with a regular expression? something like ex: `rstrip(r'\s')` trailing white space characters or ex: trailing backslash `rstrip(r'\\')`